# upwrap HTML of selected text using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a wysiwyg editor and I am unable to remove the HTML that was added due to the previous actions.

To reproduce the problem: Select the text and bold it. Now try to un-bold it. I am able to remove the class but not the wrapping `<span>`. [I have logged the HTML in the console on every click event.]

Here is what I tried:

```
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(selectedText));
```

However, it doesnt remove the wrapping HTML.

```js
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
// Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
// At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6

function replaceSelectedText(className) {
    var selectedText, sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();        
        console.log(selectedText);
        // check if selection has a class
        if(isChrome){
            if(sel.baseNode.parentElement.className && sel.rangeCount){
                console.log("isChrome className:" + sel.baseNode.parentElement.className);
                sel.baseNode.parentElement.className = "";
                
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();  // doesnt delete the wrapping HTML
                range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(selectedText));
                
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        if(isFirefox){
            if(sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling.className){
                console.log("isFirefox className:" + sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling.className);
                sel.anchorNode.nextElementSibling.className = "";
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        
        //console.log(selectedText);
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var element = document.createElement('span');
            element.className = className;
            element.textContent = selectedText;
            range.insertNode(element);
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.text = replacementText;
    }
}

var toolbarButtons = document.querySelectorAll("#toolbar button");
//console.log(toolbarButtons);
for (var i = 0; i < toolbarButtons.length; ++i) {
    toolbarButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        replaceSelectedText(this.id);
        console.log(document.getElementById("editable").innerHTML);
    });
}
```

```css
#editable{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.bold{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.italic{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
    <button id="bold">Bold</button>
    <button id="italic">Italic</button>
</div>

<div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by filtering out the `<span>` with no `className` using regex when the user submits the form.

```
sourceHTML = sourceHTML.replace(/\<span class=""\>([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)\<\/span\>/g, "$1");
```